# Error in file(file, "rt")

Tags: r

I'm using Rstudio and I cannot open several file .txt because of this error message :

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

I enter :

```
X1= read.table("fileX1.txt", header = FALSE)
```

I don't understand because some of my colleagues use the same function with the same `.txt` file and it works for them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you aren't specifying the path to the file, R will look for it in the current directory.  If that isn't the directory containing the file, you'll get that error.

You can use `setwd()` (or a menu command in RStudio) to set the current directory.  Alternatively, you could use `file.choose()` to get a dialog to choose the file; it will return the full filename including the path.